# Assign Label.Text from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a label in aspx page. I am trying to assign text to that label according to my search criteria. My problem is if i put that label (lblMsge) inside  I am unable to assign the text from code behind. if i put that label outside the tr its working fine but the display is not proper. Please see the Image. I tried by putting that label in div tags also. But still no luck Can any one help me. Here is my code.

```
<tr id="trResults" visible="false" style="height: 700px;" runat="server">
                    <td valign="top" style="width: 100%;" align="center">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6" align="center" width="98%">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsge" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" BackColor="Yellow"
                                        ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                                    <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                                    </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                                    <div style="width: 98%; height: 600px; overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden">
                                        <telerik:RadGrid ID="gvPjtMnt" runat="server">

                                        </telerik:RadGrid>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>


            if (gvPjtMnt.Items.Count <= 0)
        {
            lblMsge.Text = "No records found, please change the search criteria and try again.";
        }
        else
        {
            trResults.Visible = true;
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.upRes, this.GetType(), "RecCount", "document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_gvPjtMnt_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_lblTotRecCount').innerHTML='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + "'", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure a Label is the correct control to use?  Labels are intended to semantically specify a.. well.. Label for another control.  If you are not tying a Label to a control, chances are you are not using Labels as they are intended.

You most likely want to use a Literal control.

Second, your sample code doesn't make much sense, nor does your description.  Are you actually putting your source code in with your aspx?  Can you explain further what you mean by "Unable to assign"?

Comment: My guess is that its a naming container issue. Like when putting a Web control in a template you can no longer reference it - you have to use FindControl.

Comment: That's possible, but doesn't make sense given the context.  That would mean his HTML would likely be in a Template, and then he wouldn't be able to access it elsewhere in the table as he claims.

Comment: @Scott Mitchell is right - the TR is runat=server (i have no idea why). Therefore he should get a handle of that and use FindControl on that.